# Smarty exception: "Please use parent::__construct() to call parent constructor"

Tags: php, smarty, runtime-error

I'm following a tutorial and after setting everything up I'm getting:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'SmartyException' with message 'Please
>   use parent::__construct() to call parent constuctor'

This is my config file:

```
<?php
// SITE_ROOT contains the full path to the tshirtshop folder
define('SITE_ROOT', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
// Application directories
define('PRESENTATION_DIR', SITE_ROOT . '/presentation/');
define('BUSINESS_DIR', SITE_ROOT . '/business/');
// Settings needed to configure the Smarty template engine
define('SMARTY_DIR', SITE_ROOT . '/libs/smarty/');
define('TEMPLATE_DIR', PRESENTATION_DIR . 'templates');
define('COMPILE_DIR', PRESENTATION_DIR . 'templates_c');
define('CONFIG_DIR', SITE_ROOT . '/include/configs');
?>
```

My directory structure is:

```
mydomain.com/test/include
mydomain.com/test/libs
mydomain.com/test/presentation
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Does the error message not also tell you which line the error is on?

Comment: Is this PHP4 code ran in a PHP5 environment?

Comment: no it is in the PHP5 environment

Comment: Bob, instead of changing the question title to contain "Solved", please accept one of the answers to the question. If none of them answered it, add your own answer with what you did to solve the problem, and accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

This means there is a class extending the Smarty class that is using __construct method that needs to contain something like:

```
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}
```

this will call the smarty construct method which looks something like this:

```
public function __construct()
{ 
        // selfpointer need by some other class methods
        $this->smarty = $this;
    if (is_callable('mb_internal_encoding')) {
        mb_internal_encoding(SMARTY_RESOURCE_CHAR_SET);
    } 
    $this->start_time = microtime(true); 
    // set default dirs
    $this->template_dir = array('.' . DS . 'templates' . DS);
    $this->compile_dir = '.' . DS . 'templates_c' . DS;
    $this->plugins_dir = array(SMARTY_PLUGINS_DIR);
    $this->cache_dir = '.' . DS . 'cache' . DS;
    $this->config_dir = '.' . DS . 'configs' . DS;
    $this->debug_tpl = SMARTY_DIR . 'debug.tpl';
    if (isset($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])) {
        $this->assignGlobal('SCRIPT_NAME', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
    } 
}
```

Comment: so i need to change something here:

Comment: '<?php
// Reference Smarty library
require_once SMARTY_DIR . 'Smarty.class.php';
/* Class that extends Smarty, used to process and display Smarty
files */
class Application extends Smarty
{
// Class constructor
public function __construct()
{
// Call Smarty's constructor
parent::Smarty();
// Change the default template directories
$this->template_dir = TEMPLATE_DIR;
$this->compile_dir = COMPILE_DIR;
$this->config_dir = CONFIG_DIR;
}
}
?>'

Comment: I would try searching in your project for "extends Smarty" to try and find the class that needs to call Smarty parent::construct

Comment: // Call Smarty's constructor
parent::Smarty();

Comment: im not understanding what needs to change though?

Comment: Change `parent::Smarty();` to `parent::__construct();`

Answer (score 3):

From your comments, your Application class constructor needs to call `parent::__construct()`, not `parent::Smarty()`.

```
<?php

// Reference Smarty library 
require_once SMARTY_DIR . 'Smarty.class.php';

/* Class that extends Smarty, used to process and display Smarty files */
class Application extends Smarty {

    // Class constructor
    public function __construct() {

        // Call Smarty's constructor 
        // parent::Smarty(); // not this
        parent::__construct(); // this

        // Change the default template directories 
        $this->template_dir = TEMPLATE_DIR;
        $this->compile_dir = COMPILE_DIR;
        $this->config_dir = CONFIG_DIR;
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: thanks but i tried that already - i get a different error message:
Uncaught exception 'SmartyException' with message 'Unable to load template file 'store_front.tpl''

Comment: also had to modify config file but it is now working - thanks

Answer (score 1):

this [link](http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=75592) will be helpful.
this->Smarty() constructor is recognized by PHP4 and parent::__construct() by PHP5. Error occurs when you use this->Smarty() in PHP5.